# What causes the blur when my fingers are almost touching?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, black-holes, quantum-information, atoms

[image: A blur can be seen when fingers almost touch]

I can see this with my bare eyes
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially observing an interference effect. This is equivalent to what you would see in a single slit experiment.

The fringes are caused as the light rays that passes between your fingers are travelling slightly different distance to reach you eye.  This causes their phases to be somewhat different. As a result the light rays partially cancel, causing the blur.

Comment: Isn't it diffraction?

Comment: It would be interesting to see why we only see a diffraction minimum and no maxima. Maybe it's because the source is incoherent.

Comment: You can see The minimums and maximums. This picture is not clear but if you look real close in your own fingers you will see stripes of dark lines.  The dark stripes or minimums and in between our maximum.